# How to classify words which are written differently

Tags: r

If the word WAGONRI is written in different ways, for example,
WGNRI,WGR,WAG,ABD-WGR1, how can we classify the word written as a WAGONRI

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stringdistance` from `stringdist` to determine if the strings are similar and then use a suitable cut-off.

```
stringdist::stringdist("WAGONRI",c("WGNRI","WGR","WAG","ABD-WGR1"))
[1] 2 4 4 7
```

If you have few words each written in a few different ways, it might be easiest to hard-code the rules. Use e.g. `if_else`

```
x <- c("WGNRI","WGR","WAG","ABD-WGR1")
if_else(WORD %in% x, "WAGONRI", Something else)
```

Comment: hi, i tried string distance method for a large number of text along with a dendogram. the dendogram is hard to read due to so many text. i want to get these to a table but there should be a  column for the cluster name

Comment: hi danu, i would suggest that you post a new question, with an example of your input data, and wanted output. Based on your vague description it is difficult to provide suggestions. good luck!